# How to fix an undefined method in a simple class in Python for maya script?

Tags: python, maya

To get a better understanding of how classes are called and work, I have been trying to take a handful of functions that have been working for me in a simple script I have written that snaps one object to another in 3D space in maya.

When I put them in a class and try to run the code, the error message that I got was:

> Error: NameError: file  line 10: global name 'runSelected' is not defined #

I thought that this might be because I was calling methods that did not have `self.` in front of them. I tried doing this though and am still getting an error which is:

> Error: NameError: file  line 35: global name 'self' is
>   not defined #

The script is run after selecting two objects in 3D space in maya and kicked off by running:

`Align()`

The code for the class is below:

```
#Class for snapping one object to another in Maya.

import maya.cmds as mc


class Align(object):

    def __init__(self):
        #starts the runSelected Method
        self.runSelected()       

    def selectionCheck(mySel):
        #checks that 2 ojects are created, returns True if so, Flase if not.
        if len(mySel) == 2:   
           print "Great! Two selected"  
           return True

        elif len(mySel) == 0: 
           print "Nothing Selected to constrain!"
           return False   

    def createWindow():
        #This creates a simple dialogue window that gives a message.
        mc.confirmDialog(title='Align Objects', m ="Instructions: You need to select two objects to constrain.")

    def runConstrainDelete(mySel):
        #Creates a parent constraint, does not maintain offset and then deletes the constraint when object is moved.Clears selection.
        myParentConstraint = mc.parentConstraint(mySel[0], mySel[1], mo=False)
        mc.delete(myParentConstraint)
        mc.select (clear=True)

    def runSelected(object):
        #Creates a list of objects selected. Runs selection check
        mySel = mc.ls(sl =True)
        result_Sel_Check = self.selectionCheck(mySel)

        #if statement handles if a warning window or the rest of the script should be run.
        if result_Sel_Check == False:
            self.createWindow()    
        else:
            self.runConstrainDelete(mySel)


test_Align = Align()
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When defining instance method you need to explicitly pass `self` as a first parameter of a method. For example `def runSelected(object):`
should be changed to `def runSelected(self, object):`, only then you can access `self` in method body. You should read up on python `self` and instance methods to gain some intuition.

Comment: Ah I see, I didn't realise that I needed to pass self as an argument for all the methods in a class but that makes sense and the script is working for me now. Will look into self and instance methods as you suggest. Thanks for your help with this.

Answer (score 1):

When creating a class you have to include `self` as the first parameter for each function inside of it (unless you're trying to do class or static methods). [This has a pretty good explanation](https://micropyramid.com/blog/understand-self-and-__init__-method-in-python-class/) on how to use `self` with classes.

You also forgot to pass a parameter on `self.runSelected` in your `__init__`!

This seems to be working as expected:

```
#Class for snapping one object to another in Maya.

import maya.cmds as mc


class Align(object):

    def __init__(self):
        #starts the runSelected Method
        self.runSelected(cmds.ls(sl=True))  # Forgot to pass a parameter here.       

    def selectionCheck(self, mySel):
        #checks that 2 ojects are created, returns True if so, Flase if not.
        if len(mySel) == 2:   
           print "Great! Two selected"  
           return True

        elif len(mySel) == 0: 
           print "Nothing Selected to constrain!"
           return False   

    def createWindow(self):
        #This creates a simple dialogue window that gives a message.
        mc.confirmDialog(title='Align Objects', m ="Instructions: You need to select two objects to constrain.")

    def runConstrainDelete(self, mySel):
        #Creates a parent constraint, does not maintain offset and then deletes the constraint when object is moved.Clears selection.
        myParentConstraint = mc.parentConstraint(mySel[0], mySel[1], mo=False)
        mc.delete(myParentConstraint)
        mc.select (clear=True)

    def runSelected(self, object):
        #Creates a list of objects selected. Runs selection check
        mySel = mc.ls(sl =True)
        result_Sel_Check = self.selectionCheck(mySel)

        #if statement handles if a warning window or the rest of the script should be run.
        if result_Sel_Check == False:
            self.createWindow()    
        else:
            self.runConstrainDelete(mySel)


test_Align = Align()
```

By the way if you are using Maya 2016 and above you can use `cmds.matchTransform` to align objects. It will also take offset pivots into account. Otherwise you can use `cmds.xform` to align objects. Try to avoid creating parent constraints to align as it will be slower on performance and then you have to worry about cleaning up the scene.

Answer (score 0):

Every class method using self must have *self* in parameter list. Others, like createWindow, runConstrainDelete and selectionCheck should be static method (or defined outside the class).

Comment: Thanks for your help!